# My Magento version 1.9 suddenly reported an error yesterday,There has been an error processing your request

Tags: magento-1.9

My Magento version 1.9 suddenly reported an error yesterday. Before that, I didn't make any changes. Consulted the service provider, they said cPanel was not updated.
Edit with current solution: I've edited the /lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php replacing all iconv_strpos with strpos and it works for now.[image]But, I found that the product does not display currency, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try update your PHP version to 7